# Incorrect syntax in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm sure this is simple, and after saring at it for the last 30 mins I still can't see what I have done wrong.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spR_GetDetails]
    @UserEmail varchar(300),
    @SentName varchar(300),
    @SentEmail varchar(300),
    @UserId int OUTPUT,
    @UserName varchar(300) OUTPUT,
    @SentId int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DELCARE @Checker int
    SET @Checker = (SELECT COUNT(UserId) AS Checker FROM AccountReps WHERE UserEmail = @UserEmail)

    IF  @Checker > 0 
    BEGIN

    END
    ELSE 

    END
END
```

the three lines in question are

```
        DELCARE @Checker int
    SET @Checker = (SELECT COUNT(UserId) AS Checker FROM AccountReps WHERE UserEmail = @UserEmail)

    IF  @Checker > 0
```

since adding these I get the error "Incorrect syntax near 'DELCARE'."

thanks

Comment: You mean `declare`. Also, "staring", not saring.

Comment: You have another error: the `ELSE` branch has `END` but has no corresponding `BEGIN`

Comment: OMG, you look at it for so long you miss the really obvious thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your DECLARE is wrong.

You must use DECLARE instead of DELCARE.